# Start new mac terminal window with new process

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, process, fork

I'm using fork() to create new process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) 
{
    switch (fork())
    {
        case -1: exit(0);
        case 0: {
            execl("Terminal.app", "shell", "-e", "time ls; shell", (char*)0);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
            initscr();
            time_t secs = time(NULL);
            tm* timeInfo = localtime(&secs);
            printw("TIME: %s", asctime(timeInfo));
            getch();
            endwin();
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

This code should create new console window and make `time ls`, but it doesn't. What is the problem?

Comment: What does it do?  Have you tried calling `open -a Terminal.app` instead of just Terminal.app?

Comment: @RichardBarber, I'll trying to from one console window open another

Comment: You mean a separate instance of the Terminal.app.

Comment: You’ll also need the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `open -a -n Terminal.app` to run a new instance of the app (even though one is already running).

Comment: rly? I wanna do this from my c++ program, not from console.

Comment: Yes, don’t use the name of the app container to execute it.  Use `open`.

Comment: You’ll have to parse it to suit

Comment: Just in case anyone else runs across this answer, I needed to change the command to `open -n -a Terminal.app` to get it to work. I also referenced https://ss64.com/osx/open.html.